# I’m trying to figure out how to make a percent chance system in Python and can’t figure out why my code won’t work

Tags: python, variables, integer, user-input, var

The code itself is using the variable `x` which starts as `0` and `num` which is `x % 2`.

The code takes `x` and adds `1` or `2` to `x` depending on user input. An example of the functionality is:

```
if num != int: print('hi')
```

and a contrasting statement:

```
elif num == int: print("hello")
```

The code always prints `"hi"` no matter if `num` is a whole number or a fraction.

Comment: How are you taking in the input?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, why should `num` ever be equal to `int`? (Hint: is a blue ball *equal to* the colour blue? What would that even mean?)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `isinstance`:

```
if not isinstance(num, int):
```

`int` is a type. You want to see if your number has that type, not if your number is the type int.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the built-in [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function:

```
num = 5

if type(num) != int: 
    print('hi') 
elif type(num) == int: # Ideally, this should just be "else:"
    print("hello")
```

Output:

```
hello
```

Do note that there exists another built-in function, [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), that can do the same thing:

```
num = 5

if isinstance(num, int): 
    print('hello') 
else: 
    print('hi')
```

Output:

```
hello
```

**BUT**, you should keep in mind that this would also return `True` if `num` were the boolean value of `True`:

```
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
```